# How to increase size of Chip?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried a couple of things to make the chip bigger but nothing I tried until now (like SizedBox etc) worked.

Also couldn't find anything in the documentation of Chip:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html

Would appreciate some help

```
_buildChip() {
return Expanded(
    child: Chip(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
  avatar: SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      width: 60,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
      )),
  label: Text("awd"),
));
```

}

Comment: Maybe a Chip is not what you're looking for... you could achieve a desire result with a Container having a Row as a child. Chip UI is very specific and has a tiny icon and a label/text next to it.

Comment: you can always create a custom chip